# Scilab polynomial interpolation of covid 19 day-by-day new infected

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I am trying to understand how polynomial interpolation works and how I should implement it on Scilab. A friend suggested to see covid-19 day-by-day new infected and to compare the polynomial interpolation with the real data. I understood how it works in the theorical aspect, but I didn't understand how to do it in practice. I don't have any instrument and my friends are using Scilab, so I think I'll do it too. So I have Italian open data about covid19, but how can I get them together and work on them? Has anybody done the same thing so far? Can you link me examples please? Thanks

Comment: I doubt you actually mean "polynomial interpolation".  You probably mean optimized fitting to some polynomial or piecewise polynomial, or something like that.  What is it exactly that you hope to model? What specific function? Why do you believe it is well described by a polynomial?

Comment: While learning about polynomial interpolation during an online course, the lecturer suggested, as an easy example for yourself, to use it to describe covid19's curve. He said something about getting the number of new infected day-by-day and to use polynomial interpolation to see "what we should expect in an utopic future". I didn't quite understand it. I asked more info, but I still don't get it, so I am posting here.

Comment: That's extremely vague.  Polynomial interpolation requires that the polynomial actually pass through the points in question, and that is almost always a bad idea in modeling. In the present situation, the data is known to be quite inaccurate.  The Italian hospitals were, sadly, quite overwhelmed by the virus and the data they yielded is extremely unreliable as a result.  Fitting to that data exactly almost certainly means fitting to noise.

Comment: For a quick solution, I suggest doing a linear recursion on something like a running average.  On the existing data, first check to see how good such a thing is as a predictor (it might be awful).  If it looks ok, then you can hope that it is an ok predictor for the short term future.

Comment: If all you really want is practice with finding interpolating polynomials, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InterpolatingPolynomial%5B%281%2C2%29%2C%282%2C1%29%2C%283%2C2%29%2C%284%2C1%29%2C+%285%2C6%29%5D) can handle it.  my link gives you a simple example, seeking a quartic which goes through $5$ data points (which I chose randomly).

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious advise!